# Java audio doesn't play in jar file

Tags: java, file, audio, jar

with netbeans i've created a JFrame with 3 buttons wich let me start a wav sound file loop it or stop it. If i launch it from netbeans it works perfectly but if i launch jar file it doesn't work
What's wrong?

Here the code

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */

    private AudioData audiodata;
    private AudioDataStream audiostream;
    private ContinuousAudioDataStream continuousaudiostream;

    public NewJFrame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        initComponents();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("boing.wav");
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(fis);
        audiodata = audioStream.getData();
        audiostream = null;
        continuousaudiostream = null;
    }

    public void play() {
        audiostream = new AudioDataStream(audiodata);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audiostream);
    }

    public void loop() {
        continuousaudiostream = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audiodata);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(continuousaudiostream);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (audiostream != null)
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(audiostream);
        if (continuousaudiostream != null)
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(continuousaudiostream);
    }

   }
```

The play(), loop() and stop() methods are invoked by my 3 buttons. My "boing.wav" file is inside my project folder, i tried also put it into /src/"boing.wav" but never works launching jar file.
What should i do?

Comment: Make sure the audio file is located on your classpath folder

Comment: my audio file is inside project folder but doesn't work

Comment: try putting it into /bin/ folder, or hard coding the wav file location

Comment: Did you ensure that when you create the jar, that the file is included inside the jar as well?

Comment: @CedricSimon in my neatbeans project folder isn't /bin/ folder :(

Comment: Put it to whatever your compiled class folder is, or put it into C:/temp/ and set new FileInputStream("/temp/boing.wav"). For testing purpose, not production....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something to do with your jdk or sound card. The code looks ok, tho. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the jdk. Also, test the app on a different system and let's know what the response is.